Dependency version library without version
I just realized that my build.gradle is implementing dependency without version
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

I want to update the version into the latest stable,
so it will become
implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.1")

but issue happen when I update the version, few of My code is deprecated and I need to rebuild my code base if I want to implement the 1.2.1 version.
my question is, how to know what current version I use if I dont write the version explicitly?

somewhere in your gradle file you probably have a lines similar to this
def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00')
implementation composeBom and that bom dependency is what version you have for stuff

An easy way to find out is to go use your IDE to go to the definition of a component in that artifact. In this case, you can use a Text composable, middle-click it and hover the mouse over the newly opened tab in the tab row. It will display the path on the filesystem, which will also include the version number somewhere in the middle.

thanks guys,
I think the easy way still be easier.
